# How to change datasource of a widget with script in Google AppMaker?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have started a new project of data gestion.
I have Created a server script to create new tables with sql queries on my google cloud sql database. I want with a script display these tables on a table widget on a page of AppMaker but it's seems that it's not possible to do that automaticaly.

Is there a way to update the datasource of a widget with script?

Comment: No. There isn't a feature to change the datasource of a widget dynamically for now.